# writing mqtt payload to spiffs file

Tags: mqtt, spiffs

I'm trying to write the payload of a MQTT message into a file in the SPIFFS file system of my esp32 board. I've tried this:

```
if(file.print((long)payload)) {
   Serial.println("File was written");
}else {
   Serial.println("File write failed");
}
```

payload is a byte* and file was opened in the setup() function like:

```
File file;
if(!SPIFFS.exists("/testfile")){
  file = SPIFFS.open("/testfile", "r+");
}
```

I always get an error when writing to it telling me that the file write failed. Is this the correct approach for what I'm trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

Use `file.write(payload, length);` for byte array. `length` should be the count of payload bytes, not the size of the payload array.

`print` and `write` return the count of bytes written. It is not meaningful to use the return value as boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Open the file in the loop or the subroutine, but not in setup as file is then a local var to setup

In your code it should be

```
file = SPIFFS.open("/testfile", "a"); // a ... append
```

> a      Open for appending (writing at end of file).  The file is
>          created if it does not exist.  The stream is positioned at the
>          end of the file.

r+   positions stream at the beginning of the file

and to get lines you can afterwards analyze you should use

```
if(file){
   file.println("Your MQTT payload");
   Serial.println("File was written");
   file.close();
} else {
    Serial.println("File write failed");
}
```

and do not forget to close after the operation.
**EDIT**
As reaction to the comments here a "clean solution" as a function:

```
bool writeLog(const char fileName[],  char payloadMqtt[]) {
  File logFile = SPIFFS.open(fileName, "a");
  if (!logFile)  {
        Serial.println("logFile open failed");
    return false;
  }
  else {
    //Write data to file
    Serial.println("writing Data to logFile");
    logFile.print(payloadMqtt);
    logFile.close();
    return true;
  }
}
```

You call it with:

```
writeLog("/myfilepath", payload);
```

and can also be used like

```
if (writeLog("/myfilepath", payload)) Serial.println("Log save success");
else Serial.println("Log save failure");
```

Hope this helps to understand the nature of SPIFFS/LittleFS/SD operations

Comment: Sorry, I put FIle file; outside the setup(), but I open it inside. And it doesn't make much sense to me to open the file inside the loop. Also, my problem is that payload is a byte array so I guess I need a casting to write that into the file

Comment: You should only open before writing and close after writing, we are on a MCU not a full scale OS. Look into the lib spiffs_api.h/cpp to see what open means for your memory (aside from unwanted errors andother probs) . If your payload is a char array you just use file.println(payload)